Is "Shopping malls are a posh place" grammatical when "malls" is a plural and "place" is a singular?

Shopping malls are a posh place.

I read some sentences using "a plural + be + a singular" somewhere before, but I couldn't remember which context it was, or it was just a writing error. But I researched this kind of structure today and haven't got the answer.
So I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatical when "malls" is a plural and "place" is a singular?

Hi, I'm afraid that asking for text to be checked for errors is off-topic on this site. Your question must be on a point of learning English. It sounds like you've already got an inkling it is wrong - why not research that yourself? If you don't understand what you find in research, bring that back and ask for an explanation - that could possibly form the basis of a valid question.

You're correct to sense that the sentence doesn't work.  Shopping malls are posh places.  But it would be hard to state the grammatical rule, since "Beaches are a fun place to visit" isn't as awkward. It's probably "to visit" that eases the number clash.

@Astralbee Thank you for reminding me, I will edit my question to explain more explicitly. I already researched it but I haven't found the right answer. I read some sentences using "a plural + be + a singular" somewhere, but I couldn't remember which context it was, or it was just a writing error.

@TimR "isn't as awkward" means it's still awkward?

It's conversational, so awkwardness doesn't matter as much.

Does this answer your question? Plural or singular in these sentences

@StuartF Thank you, as I read in that question's answer, the normal expression is "Prison is the best option for serial killers". But don't we have to add an article before "prison" as it's a singular noun?

Dear Phoebe, it sounds like you don't know what 'posh' means. Fortnum and Mason or Harrods are posh. Your average shopping mall is not.

@MichaelHarvey In my country, shopping malls are often considered luxurious places as they have beautiful designs and upmarket brands are often located there. If "posh" isn't suitable in this context, could you suggest an alternative to it to me?

Better make that a new question. Shopping mall is also AmEng, in Britain they were commonly called shopping centres. They are a few in the fancier parts of London which I would call high class. I'm trying to think of the Victorian (?) lane or avenue's name but it's not coming to me.

@Mari-LouA - I'm trying to think of it also, but it's not coming to me either. Unless you mean the Burlington Arcade? I would say the these days 'mall' is as widely used as 'covered shopping centre' in the UK, especially in casual contexts. I regularly go to somewhere at the edge of Bristol called officially 'The Mall at Cribbs Causeway'.

@MichaelHarvey Burlington Arcade Yes, that's the one!

@Mari-LouA - I love those arcade places! They still exist; there's one in Brixton, south London, that is definitely not 'posh'. My parents used to take me there when I was a kid. https://www.brixtonbuzz.com/2014/12/see-how-brixton-village-looked-in-1961-with-pathes-caribbean-market-footage-of-granville-arcade/

@MichaelHarvey  The video in that article is great! That man's voice, RP in its purest form, you never hear that type of voice nowadays (thankfully). That's what I call a posh voice. Have to go now :(

@Mari-LouA - if you saw a little 9-year-old white kid in the background, that could have been me. I would call the man's voice very traditional 'cut glass'/RP in the way that British TV and radio required in 1961.  Now the object of mirth.

How on earth does this have four votes to close as "proofreading"? There is a clear concern. Sometimes I think people have gotten the idea that the problem with proofreading questions is that someone is looking for immediate, practical, and specific help; the problem really is that they're often too broad and open-ended, a request to spot errors in a whole paragraph where there might be none, leading to very divergent and unhelpful answers.

(Looking at the history, I see, because there was much less to the question at first. Well, maybe it's time to retract a few votes.)

@MichaelHarvey: There are still some people stuck in remote rural locations, for whom a trip to the nearest shopping mall might be the best they can do in terms of seeing the bright lights. And that's true even of native Anglophones. Obviously not all, but I'm sure the average English learner is even more likely to be in that situation. And that's not to mention "shanty town" denizens in many less developed countries.

@AndyBonner I guess it’s voted “close” because there’re questions asking about this before. But with this kind of question, it’s kinda hard for me to find the right key word to discover previous questions beforehand.

@Phoebe It's true, it's good to check. But when voting to close, you pick a reason, and by now 3 people have picked the "proofreading" reason. By the way, you can see more about what's covered and what's not here. It's true that the first version of this question didn't have much explanation, but it has certainly met that "proofreading" requirement since you edited it (and maybe even before).

No, *Shopping malls are a posh place is not idiomatic. We form a predicate with a singular noun after a plural predicand only when conceiving of the predicand as a class. Thus,

Sunglasses are one way to protect your eyes from UV light

or

Shopping malls are an idea that may be making a comeback.


@Phoebe Note, some examples could go either way. "Shopping malls are seen as a threat by local businesses": Means local shops say "Shopping malls [in general, as a whole] are a threat!" "Shopping malls are seen as threats by local businesses": Means many shops look at a specific mall and say "That mall is a threat!"

As a stylistic comment, I'd suggest that "might" should be preferred to "may" in this context, i.e. "an idea that might be". From the POV of somebody who has done a lot of technical etc. writing, the problem with "may" is that it might be parsed either as "might happen" or "is permitted to happen", and avoiding the ambiguity is advisable if possible.

"...malls are...an idea..." sounds weird to me. I would try "The shopping mall is an idea..." if I needed a singular verb. Or something like "The idea of shopping malls is...

It might look "illogical", but I think most native Anglophones are quite comfortable with...

Pubs are a good place to [drink beer].
Schools are a good place to [learn stuff]
Stores are a good place to [buy stuff]
[Shopping] malls are a good place to [hang out]

I know those all feature ...a good place to..., but there are also lots of...

...a posh place to...

Every one of those lines links to at least dozens of published written instances, and I'm quite sure people do it more often in speech than they would in formal written contexts. It's pointless and pedantic to rail against the construction.

I will at least acknowledge that...

[plural] are an [adjective] place
...as a standalone utterance, such as...
Pubs are a good place

...isn't remotely idiomatic. But I hope my examples with infinitive-based "adverb of purpose" clauses have convinced you that in the right context, there's nothing inherently wrong with [plural] are an [adjective] place.

"Pubs are a good place to...." might be heard commonly, but it's ungrammatical. I would change it to "pubs are good places to...." if I were copyediting that. It's not hard to make the noun agree in number...

Well, like I said above, It's pointless and pedantic to rail against the construction. But I'm not gonna argue the toss. People have different opinions. Except I can't resist linking this chart showing that Pubs are good places isn't recorded often enough to chart, whereas Pubs are a good place is there.

No, that is incorrect. It should be:

Shopping malls are posh places.

Or

A shopping mall is a posh place.


I'd never thought of a shopping mall as a posh place, but otherwise I totally agree with this answer. "Posh is not the word" springs to mind.

Why not "Shopping malls are posh"? Still factually incorrect, but it's grammatically OK.

Yep, that works and avoids the verb-noun number disagreement.
